# How to save user state in Android?

Tags: android

I have an application for my Nokia mobile.  When I install that software and try to use it for the first time, it asks me for a password and to confirm that password.  Then after writing it and clicking on OK button, it allows me to use the application.

Now  if I close that software and open again, it asks me to write ONLY the password.  After entering the password correctly, it allows me to use its application again.  Also if I totally remove that application from the phone and install it again, it asks me to enter the password and confirm the password.

So tell me how do I write an application like this in Android?

Comment: Please try to be a bit more clear on what you want. It is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Please refer maxim answer and try to give me code for it.

Comment: You know the problem is not us not understanding your question but you not communicating it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand the question is how to realize saving a "user state" in application. If so, you can use SharedPreferences (esspecially if you have only one user state) or database. If you launch app firs time it search data in shared preferances or db. If there is no information app asks user to enter and confirm password after that it writes data to SP or db.

Prety simpe example how to use SP.
Writing to SP:

```
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = 
            context.getSharedPreferences("PASSWORD_PREFS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("PSSWORD", password);
    editor.commit();
```

Reading SP:

```
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String password = mySharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD, null);
```

You can use edit.apply() insted of commit(). It is recommended by Android team. But this method is for API Level 9. You can read about it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: finally somebody undrstood the meaining of my question .will you give me code for it.

Comment: There is only one problem with that. After you uninstall the application and install it again the `SharedPreferences` will be gone.