# how to make single user login for application in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save user state in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498905/how-to-save-user-state-in-android)

how to make single user login for application in android ,which will give us facitlity to retrive password to user.

Comment: You are going to have to provide a bit more information.  Where does the user get their login details from initially?  Does the authentication happen within the device or on the network?

Comment: You're previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498905/how-to-do-it-in-android) was asked like 40 minutes before this one. Also is a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(uid.getText().toString().equals("") && pwd.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your credentials !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uid.requestFocus();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(uid.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("demo") && pwd.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("demo"))
                    {
                        Log.i("ONLOGIN", "Login successful");
                        Intent i =new Intent(login.this, new.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        uid.setText("");
                        pwd.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e("ONLOGIN", "Invalid credentails");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should never keep password in plaintext. Make a hash from it. During login, compare this hashes...

In case when user forget a password, send a newly generated password to user by e-mail, given to you during registration.

After login with this generated password user should set new password, which hash has to be saved for the future.