# How to transition between Activity classes in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save user state in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498905/how-to-save-user-state-in-android)

My application's first activity is login1 in which i am asking user to enter password,confirm password,security question and answer(security question and answer is taken in case of retrive password to user in the form of sms or email.)

second activity is login2  having only one field to enter that is password.

third activity is main activity of my application that is setting.

Now the question is that when user enters information of all fields which are in first activity login1 then he should move to directly to setting activity.

if  user close application after setting password and  open it again he must get second activity that is login2 where he just have to enter password to login.

if he remove that application from phone and then install again he must get first activity that is login1  .

So tell me code for doing it .please replay.

Comment: Why don't you post the code you have written so far, and then we can help correct it? People on SO will not do work for you, but will be more than happy to help you fix a problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  For future reference, you may get more responses if you choose a descriptive subject.  [Note: the original subject was "i cant get it how to do it in android."  I've put in an edit, which has to be reviewed, to change it to "How to transition between Activity classes in Android?"]

Comment: Please edit your original question to add details instead of posting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 0th activity to your list as a splashscreen, or license agreement, or something, and there you could write code to chose proper activity (1st or 2nd).
Or you can merge 1st and 2nd activities to a single activity with the help of `ViewFlipper` and write your "choose code" there.