# Storing data in android phone memory and read the store data

Tags: android

I need to write the code for storing data in phone memory and reading the store data, so, need u'r help..?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of information do you whant to store? You can use db or SharedPreferences.
I answered about SP here [How to save user state in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498905/how-to-save-user-state-in-android/5499008#5499008)

Comment: actually I like to abstract user phone number from the device running my application but it's not possible in every network service provider sim... so, in that case user input the number 1'st time and further used the data for login.. these is the scenario..

Comment: We can simply store the data in the database... if anybody need the help then.. I can send the code..