# Persisting Data on Android Apps

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I want to persist with some values during the lifecycle of my app? what is the best approach? to use sqlite or is there any other alternative like noSQL based DBs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you have not so much data to save you can use Shared Preferances [How to save user state in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498905/how-to-save-user-state-in-android/5499008#5499008)

Answer (score 0):

Your options are described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).